# "In no way" vs "By no means"

Tags: phrases, differences

How do I decide whether I should use "in no way" or "by no means"? Are they different in any way? Should either of these terms be used at all?

For example:

> In no way am I suggesting that...
>
> By no means am I suggesting that...

or should I stick to something like:

> I am not suggesting that...

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: In my opinion as a native American English speaker both "in no way am I suggesting" and "by no means am I suggesting" are more confrontational than "I am not suggesting...."

Comment: @Lumberjack Thank you for that very good observation. I hadn't even considered the tone.

Comment: The first two are emphatic; the last simply factual. Of the first two, for denying any implications attach to a statement, I prefer the first ("in no way"). When describing outcomes or denying equivalence or identity of two objects, I prefer the latter ("by no means").

Comment: @Lumberjack That assumes you are speaking in a confrontational context. You might be saying, for example, 'By no means burden yourself on my account...'

Comment: Thanks guys. If these were the first three words of a disclaimer, does it seem like "In no way" is the best option?

Comment: @WS2 Thanks for the addition.  I concur.  Dan's word "emphatic" is probably a better choice than my "confrontational."

Comment: If you can avoid including yourself, "It is not being suggested" deflects a bit from this being a personal defense and more directly focuses on the item for discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are very similar phrases. Both are usually stronger than the raw *I am not suggesting*.

They both suggest that a reader could attempt to construct a multitude of arguments leading from the preceding discussion to whatever unfortunate suggestion follows, and that every single such line of implicit reason is denied by the author.

That you have added words to this effect suggests that you are defending against such a position and so could be seen as defensive or, in other contexts, merely robust.

A *means* in this context refers to a process or system designed to some particular end and purpose -- "I will escape the prison by *means* of a rope ladder"; -- as does a *way*, by the metaphor of a path from a problem to a solution, -- "I will solve this problem the old-fashioned *way*". All such means (and ways) of building whatever conclusion follows are denied by the author.

I find it impossible to separate the two expressions.

Some people prefer "I am by no means suggesting that..." and "I am in no way suggesting that" which seem slightly more idiomatic and common than your original construction (a conclusion also supported by search counts).

Comment: +1 "ways and means" - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ways%20and%20means

Comment: I was going to mention that the UK has a "Chairman of Ways and Means", but thought it excessively parenthetical. I had no idea that the title had crossed the herring pond. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chairman_of_Ways_and_Means